# createBottomTabNavigator: hide just one tab from the tabBar

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using createBottomTabNavigator and listing all my pages there in a file called Navigator.js. The problem is that i have one page called 'AboutScreen' and i don't want to show in the TabNavigator. I just need this 'AboutScreen' there to use

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AboutScreen')}
```

on another screen called SettingScreen.js. When i use that function above with the AboutScreen instanced in Navigator.js the navigation works but 'AboutScreen' appears in the bottom tab, that's what i don't want. Is there a way to hide only this page 'AboutScreen' that appears in my bottom tab? My codes below:

```
//This is Navigator.js

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home:               {screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor, activeTintColor}) => (
               <Icon name="home" size={19} color={tintColor} />
               )
        },},
    Catalog:            {screen: CatalogScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Catalog',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor, activeTintColor}) => (
               <Icon name="local-library" size={19} color={tintColor} />
               )
        },},
    MyLibrary:          {screen: MyLibraryScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'My Library',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor, activeTintColor}) => (
               <Icon name="star" size={19} color={tintColor} />
               )
        },},
    Setting:            {screen: SettingScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Setting',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor, activeTintColor}) => (
               <Icon name="settings" size={19} color={tintColor} />
               )
        },},
        AboutScreen:               {screen: AboutScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'AboutScreen',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor, activeTintColor}) => (
                <Icon name="home" size={19} color={tintColor} />
                )
        },},
},{
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    swipeEnabled: true,
    showIcon: true,
    tabBarOptions:{
        showIcon: true,
        showLabel: true,
        activeTintColor: '#FEFEFE',
        inactiveTintColor: '#614B70',
        activeBackgroundColor: '#614B70',
        inactiveBackgroundColor: '#FEFEFE',
    }
});
```

```
//And this is the SettingScreen.js where i want to use the 'AboutScreen'

import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, Button, Image, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class SettingScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemContainerTouchable}
        onPress={() => this.navigateScreen('Home')}>
          <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
            <Icon 
              name="settings"
              color={'#614B70'}
              style={styles.itemIcon}
            />
            <Text style={styles.itemText}>General</Text>
          </View>
          <View
          style={{height: 1, width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#614B70'}}
        />
        </TouchableOpacity>        
      </ScrollView>
    );    
  }
  navigateScreen(object) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(object);
  }
}
//styles are irrelevant
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a customBottomTabNavigator.

The one I'm using right now is this:

```
    import React from 'react'
import { BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs'
import { View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
var { height } = Dimensions.get("window")
const HiddenView = () => <View style={{ display: 'none' }} />
const TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper = ({
    onPress,
    onLongPress,
    testID,
    accessibilityLabel,
    ...props
}) => {
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            onPress={onPress}
            onLongPress={onLongPress}
            testID={testID}
            hitSlop={{
                left: 15,
                right: 15,
                top: 5,
                bottom: 5,
            }}
            accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
        >
            <View {...props} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}
export default TabBarComponent = props => {
    return <BottomTabBar
        {...props}
        style={styles.bottomBarStyle}
        getButtonComponent={({ route }) => {
            if (route.key === "ScreenToHideKey" )
                return HiddenView
            else return TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper
        }}
    />
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bottomBarStyle: {
        height: (height * 10.625) / 100   //your header height (10.625 is the %)
    }
})
```

Then where you use your createBottomTabNavigator:

```
{
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    swipeEnabled: true,
    showIcon: true,
    tabBarComponent: (props) => (<BottomBar {...props} ></BottomBar>) //remember to import it
    tabBarOptions:{
        showIcon: true,
        showLabel: true,
        activeTintColor: '#FEFEFE',
        inactiveTintColor: '#614B70',
        activeBackgroundColor: '#614B70',
        inactiveBackgroundColor: '#FEFEFE',
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StackNavigator nested inside of your BottomTabBarNavigator, in the nested StackNavigator you put the SettingsScreen first and then the AboutScreen. Then you remove from your tab bar the AboutScreen. and everything should work as expected